# Using CSS to target a style other than itself

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-applications, animation

It might only be possible with JavaScript, but I was wondering if it was possible to link one style to another with events like :focus or :hover in CSS alone.

For example, could the class "hitArea" change the "changeArea" background attribute when in focus?

```
.changeArea { background: yellow; }
.hitArea div:focus { changeArea:changeBG; }
.changeArea changeBG { background: blue; }
```

I know there is communication between styles when doing CSS animations, like in this working example:

```
.reveal {
    position:absolute;
    top:190px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:0px;

    -webkit-animation-name:reveal;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:backwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.2s;

    animation-name:reveal;
    animation-duration:0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode:backwards;
    animation-delay:0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes reveal {
    0%  { left:-900px; -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;  }
    99%     { left:-900px; -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear; }
    100%    { left:0px; }
}
```

So what is the syntax, or is it even possible, for me to communicate between other styles?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: If you want an effect add a class not change a class.

Comment: In CSS3, `:hover` or `:focus` for element A can only be used to change the style on element B if B is a descendant of A, or if B is a sibling of A that appears after A.

Comment: or a descendant of the sibling

Comment: Would be cool to be able to nest styles so that if one is triggered it sets a style rule for another. But no, as of now you should use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="hitarea">
    <div class="changeArea"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can target changeArea when hitArea is focused like this:

```
.hitarea:focus .changeArea {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This will only work when "changeArea" is some child of hitarea.

Read more on CSS Selectors and what you can do with them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible. You can take a look at http://sass-lang.com/ which allows you to do things like that.

Comment: SASS just can do things that are possible with CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If `.changeArea` is a child of `.hitArea`, yes!

```
.hitArea:focus .changeArea{ /* Styles to apply when .hitarea is hovered */ }
```

If that's not what you want, I recommend setting it up so that when `.hitArea` is focused,  javascript applies a class to `.changeArea` that has the style you want to apply.